# how to convert a double number to binary number in java?

Tags: java, binary, double

i search in this site and other for converting double value like .4 to binary  but there is no useful answers !
i know the procedure multiply by 2 if the number is bigger than 1 save the 1 subtract it and more time multiply it by 2 and so on .
help me !

```
double d = .4 ; 
double e ;
while ()
{
e = d*2; 
if (e>1) {
s[i]= 1;
e=d-1;
} else {
s[i] = 0;
}
System.out.print(s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29), and then [`Long.toBinaryString(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString%28long%29) on the result:

```
double d = 0.4;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d)));
```