# Is there a way to convert double to binary in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert double to binary in java  please can you explain with an  example  i want the output  to be like double 2.1 = binary  10.1

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you aware of what binary numbers are? `10.1` for sure isn't one.

Comment: @user16320675 I stand corrected, you're right. In terms of software I normally don't think of binary as anything other than "integer" representations and I'm not sure the OP doesn't have the same thought in mind.

Comment: @Thomas thank you guys ill try the below code I just got confused  i know IEEE but I'm having a  hard time trying to write a program  for that my intention is to let user input a  2 binary numbers and let them chose whatever  the opera they want and give them the calculated answers  I already  made that with integer but I wanna let users input doubles too

Comment: "I already made that with integer but I wanna let users input doubles too" - do you mean "integer" binary numbers and now you want to support fractions as well? What is the goal of this? Just a learning exercise or should the users actually get some value out of that? There might be practical reasons for a "fractional binary calculator" but I can't think of one atm.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah im making this for  a project and i wanted to learn about the fraction part too

Comment: @Thomas hey found a method i think it will work if you are interested heres the link https://www.codespeedy.com/convert-decimal-fraction-to-binary-in-java/


it works bro thanks for the support

Answer (score 2):

Use Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double), and then Long.toBinaryString(long) on the result:

```
double d = 0.4;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d)));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644079/how-to-convert-a-double-number-to-binary-number-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))`

```
public class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 10.1; 
        String l = Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d));
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Output will look like this

```
100000000100100001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of how doubles work / are stored is not quite right. I found [this site](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/) that explains the technicality "IEEE 754 binary floating point representation" quite detailed and understandable. A more easy to understand and theoretical explanation is [the video of jan Misali how floating point works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQhj5RGtag0).
In short: floating point numbers are stored as a formula that can be used to calculate the exact value. It is not stored as 'the number before and the number after the point'.

Regardless, maybe you can elaborate more on why you need this to receive more helpful answers.